# how to redirect different login page according to type of users specified in django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-login, django-logging

i created user -

1. user 1 assigned group A
2. user 2 assigned group B
   now i created login page and after login as user1 i want to redirect to page1.html
   and if logged in as user2 then redirect to page2.html
   for this
   i wrote

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            if user.usergroup=='A':
                return redirect('pages/page1.html')
            else:
                return redirect('pages/page2.html')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Invalid credentials')
            return redirect('login')
            # User is authenticate  
    else:
        return render(request,'pages/login.html')
```

with this i logged in as user1 ,got the error
**AttributeError at /
'User' object has no attribute 'usergroup'**
kindly help
is there any other code too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if user.groups.filter(name='A').exists():
    return redirect('pages/page1.html')
else:
    return redirect('pages/page2.html')
```